# Solr text search not working with long queries

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, pysolr

I'm not an expert in Solr and I'm trying it to check it's capabilities.

I'm having this odd behaviour where I'm getting good results if my text search query is composed of max 3 words, and zero results if the query is bigger.

What I did:

1. Created a docker with solr and core named `my_core`:

   `docker run -d -p 8983:8983 --name my_solr solr solr-precreate my_core`
2. In the dashboard created a new Field, named `campo_teste`, with the type `text_pt` because I need to index a dataset of Portuguese texts.
3. Added and indexed my corpus with `pysolr`.
4. Now at query time, when I search for "subsídio de parentalidade" I get results that make sense:

[image]

5. But if I use a longer sentences I get zero results. This is an example with the same query as before but in the longer sentence "quando posso pedir o subsídio de parentalidade?":

[image]

Any ideas of what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not searching in the same field for all your values; in the first example you're searching for `subsídio` in the `campo_text` field and `de parentalidade` in the default search field (since you didn't prefix those values with a field name).

In your second example you're searching for `quando` in the `campo_text` field and `posso pedir o subsídio de parentalidade` in the default search field (since you're not prefixing those values).

In effect, `subsídio` is present in `campo_text`, while `quando` is not - the default search field (by default `_text_`) probably has no content, so no hits are produced.

If you want to support general user queries, it's usually a better idea to use the `edismax` query handler with the `qf` (query fields) setting:

```
q=quanto posso pedir o subsídio de parentalidade&defType=edismax&qf=campo_text
```

This will search `campo_text` using all the words. You can then use `q.op=AND` or `q.op=OR` to adjust whether all words needs to be present or not, or you can use `mm` (minimum match) to adjust the profile in a more detailed way.

Comment: "_all the worse_" -> "_all the words_"?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the type of parsing Solr does. The answer from [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) shares knowledge into how Solr searches for words in a field. If you want to search in a field for example `campo_text` the text:

I want a burguer.

Then the parsed query inside Solr should be

```
parsedquery: '`campo_text`: I `campo_text`:want `campo_text`:a `campo_text`:burguer'
```

(this type of query can be accessed when using the debug=all parameter)

On my end, I tried the solution provided by [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) but noticed that using the defType = edismax turns the query to the following:

```
{'rawquerystring': 'I want a burguer',
  'querystring': 'I want a burguer',
  'parsedquery': '+(DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:i)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:want)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:a)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:burger)))',
  'parsedquery_toString': '+((text:i) (text:want) (text:a) (text:burguer))'}
```

My implementation is in Python and luckily there is a package named `solrq` which allows you to parse your text to the fields you want to search in using the `Q` Class. In my example I used `Q(text = 'I want a burguer')`. Debugging the same query I now get:

```
{'rawquerystring': 'text:I\\ want\\ a\\ burguer',
  'querystring': 'text:I\\ want\\ a\\ burguer',
  'parsedquery': 'text:i text:want text:a text:burguer',
  'parsedquery_toString': 'text:i text:want text:a text:burguer'}
```

I have tested both implementations of search queries (`defType = 'edismax'` and using the `Q` parser) on an experience I was working on where I'm looking at the accuracy of correct documents in the top `k` retrieved documents and I have obtained better results using the `Q` parser on my example:

|  | top_1 | top_3 | top_5 | top_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q_parser_bm25 | 0.3054 | 0.4469 | 0.4988 | 0.5649 |
| defType_edismax_bm25 | 0.2736 | 0.4009 | 0.4493 | 0.4988 |